# Shell script to join 5 or more json files together

Tags: json, linux, shell, cat

I am working on a project that has a lot of json documents in a large file lets call it manifest.json

The files have titles such as

a-11.json

```
{"id":"a-11",
 "name":"XN0",
  "code":"H3A8FF82820F"
  "status":"live"
}
```

a-03.json

```
{"id":"a-03",
 "name":"PF1",
  "code":"FFFF82820F"
  "status":"live"
}
```

a-09.json

```
{"id":"a-09",
 "name":"PF1",
 "code":"FFFF82820F"
 "status":"live"
}
```

What I want a shell script to do is to concatenate them all in alpha order and I am also need to wrap them like this:
    [
    {json doc},
    {json doc},
    {json doc
    ] 
with a sq bracket seperated with a ,  so that it looks like the code below-

The join command only connects two files so thats not going to work and I have tried a combination of cat and ls but it all goes a bit wrong.  I am trying to use the Linux environment rather than the MS environment here.

manifest.json

```
[
{"id":"a-03",
 "name":"PF1",
  "code":"FFFF82820F"
  "status":"live"
},
{"id":"a-09",
 "name":"PF1",
  "code":"FFFF82820F"
  "status":"live"
}, 
{"id":"a-11",
 "name":"XN0",
  "code":"H3A8FF82820F"
  "status":"live"
}

]
```

The command

```
cat a-*.json > manifest.json
```

Gives me the following with the a-11.json doc at the top, any help appreciated.

```
[
{"id":"a-11",
 "name":"XN0",
  "code":"H3A8FF82820F"
  "status":"live"
}
{"id":"a-03",
 "name":"PF1",
  "code":"FFFF82820F"
  "status":"live"
},
{"id":"a-09",
 "name":"PF1",
  "code":"FFFF82820F"
  "status":"live"
}, 

]
```

Comment: ehhm, `echo '[' >manifest.json; cat a-01.json >>manifest.json; echo , >>manifest.json; cat a-02.json >>manifest.json; ..... ; echo ']' >>manifest.json` ? If you don't wish to specify every a-NN.json explicitly, then you need a cycle

Comment: the input data is not json. there are commas missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following *bash* script (it uses arrays which aren't standard across all shells):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
declare -a jsons
jsons=(a-*.json) # ${jsons[@]} now contains the list of files to concatenate
echo '[' > manifest.json
if [ ${#jsons[@]} -gt 0 ]; then # if the list is not empty
  cat "${jsons[0]}" >> manifest.json # concatenate the first file to the manifest...
  unset jsons[0]                     # and remove it from the list
  for f in "${jsons[@]}"; do         # iterate over the rest
      echo "," >>manifest.json
      cat "$f" >>manifest.json
  done
fi
echo ']' >>manifest.json             # complete the manifest
```

Comment: This worked like a dream thank you.  The files came in strict alpha order to ensure that they appear in the manifest in the correct order all I did was change the id to take the form of a-0001.json allowing me to have up to 1000 docs in the script.  Also works in git.bash which is nice.

Answer (score 24):

You could use [`jq` utility (sed for JSON data)](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ jq -s '.' a-*.json > manifest.json
```

#### manifest.json:

```
[
  {
    "status": "live",
    "code": "H3A8FF82820F",
    "name": "XN0",
    "id": "a-11"
  },
  {
    "status": "live",
    "code": "FFFF82820F",
    "name": "PF1",
    "id": "a-03"
  },
  {
    "status": "live",
    "code": "FFFF82820F",
    "name": "PF1",
    "id": "a-09"
  }
]
```

Comment: Worked well after I snagged jq which looks to be very valuable but why does it order the value pairs such that moves to the bottom of the document?

Comment: a json object is an *unordered* collection of pairs. 1.3 version changes the input order of the keys. The order is preserved with the version in master.  To choose different order e.g., to sort by values:  `jq 'to_entries|sort_by(.value)|from_entries' a.json` See [issue #318](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/318)

Comment: i really felt excited about this, but the json file list i want to concat together is about 600k files, and it threw an error saying the file list was too long. :)

Comment: @Kristian: the issue is unrelated to `jq` e.g., `cat *.json >/dev/null` produces the same error: `bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long`. See [Solving “mv: Argument list too long”?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128559/1321)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian i agree it is an underlying problem, but what does that mean for my usage of `jq`? i was using it as `jq -s '.' *.json > output.json` ... where in that would I interject a different find-mechanism?